# Select multiple points closest to a set of coordinates

Tags: r, lidr, knn

Given a `LAS` object with x,y,z coordinates, i.e

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyz")
```

and a set of x,y,z coordinates (GCPs),

I seek a function that should return, for each point in the GCPs matrix, the x,y,z coordinates of the point in the `LAS` object that is the closest (Euclidean distance) using the x,y coordinates only.

I want to compare the z coordinates of the selected points in the cloud to the  z coordinates of the set of GCPs

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please clarify your question adding e.g. an image and some details.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. An image is not possible, but I've tried to edit my question and hopefully it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools like that in `lidR` but they are internal tools not exposed to users yet. But R has plenty of nearest neighbour search packages such as `nabor`. Below a reproducible exemple

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyz")
x <- runif(10, min(las$X), max(las$X))
y <- runif(10, min(las$Y), max(las$Y))
M <- cbind(x,y)

NN <- nabor::knn(las@data[,c("X", "Y")], M, k = 1)

sub <- las[as.numeric(NN$nn.idx)]
sub
plot(sub)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up myself doing something more general: selecting, for each focal point, those cloud points within a certain radius and saving the data of interest to a dataframe. Later I can select either the median z or that of the nearest point. As the clouds are very large, I read with filtering (-keep_circle) for each focal point. I understand this is more efficient than loading the whole cloud and then subsetting for each focal point.

Comment: Sure but that was not in your question